# custom decorated key for hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to know if it is possible in java to create a class that consists of a final key wrapped by some other fields and use it as key in a HashMap as if it were only that key. Something like this:

```
Map<Decorator, String> map = new HashMap<>();

private static class Decorator {
    private final int i;
    private String s;

    public Decorator(int i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Integer)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Integer other = (Integer) obj;
        return i == other;
    }
}
```

when I then call

```
    map.put(new Decorator(3, "some string"), "some value");
    System.out.println(map.get(3));
```

I would like to receive the proper map value "some value". Does someone know if this is possible?

Comment: That would be okay but your `equals` method is wrong. You should be type checking on `Decorator` not `Integer. Of course your integer field has to be unique for it to work properly.

Comment: The other thing is: what is `Decorator.s` and how is it used? Its key methods `hashCode` and `equals` would not normally ignore it

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want this? As I've explained in my answer it's a risky thing to try, but there's probably better approaches which we can suggest if you tell us your underlying need. This seems like [a XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 3):

You might get it to work <sup>*</sup>, but even *if you do*, there's still the problem that the `equals` method necessary for this does not conform to [the specification of `equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). Specifically this part:

> It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.

So if `x` is `new Decorator(1, "foo")` and `y` is `new Integer(1)` then `x.equals(y)` would return `true`, but `y.equals(x)` would return `false` (because `Integer` obviously doesn't know about your `Decorator`).

Now whether or not this *actually* causes any issues depends on how exactly the `Map` implementation uses `equals`. But since `equals` is defined to be symetric any implementation is free to call `equals` on either the key passed to the `get()` method or on the key stored in the map. If the map would always call `keyFromMap.equals(keyFromGetCall)` then it would work, if it did the opposite, it would not work. So fundamentally using such a wrapper will depend on implementation-specific behaviour, which makes it quite fragile.

The *specific* implementation in your question also breaks this rule:

> It is *reflexive*: for any non-null reference value `x`,  `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.

But this one could easily be fixed by just adding `if (obj == this) return true;` to the beginning, so that one's not an unsolvable problem.

<sup>* I've checked and the `HashMap.get(key)` implementation as of OpenJDK 17 calls `key.equals(keyStoredInHashMap)`, which means that having a decorator stored in the map and calling `get` with an `Integer` will not work, but the other way around might. I've made this just a footnote, because the more important part is that it can't *generally* work.</sup>

Comment: So I would need to construct a „dummy“ Decorator with my desired hashcode (Integer) just to access a value with it?

Comment: If you insist on keeping the decorator-key approach, then yes. You could try to restructure your design to not require the decorator, but how exactly that would make sense depends on your underlying goals with the decorator, which your original question doesn't contain enough details about to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 2 different types for the keys of a map. The map defines 2 type parameters, `Map<K ,V>`, and these are used in `put(K, V)` and `V get(K)`. Your `K` is `Decorator` and your `V` is `String`. Your `map.get(3)` call will always return `null` because a `Decorator` can't be equal to an `int` (not without violating the contract of `Object.equals`).

What you can do, and this is a normal thing to do, is use `Delegator`'s `int i` as an effective key. You need to fulfill 2 criteria:

1. `@Override` the `equals(Object)` method, which is used to determine which keys are duplicates, with that of your contained instance.
2. `@Override` the `hashCode()` method (always do so when overriding `equals()`), which is used by `HashMap`, with that of your contained instance.

This is called *delegation* - you delegate the functionality/behavior from the containing type to that of the contained type. Here, we are delegating the calls to `Decorator` to `int i`.

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(i); // Decorator's hash code is i's hash code
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) { // this is just an optimization, but not really needed in this case
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Decorator)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Decorator other = (Decorator) obj;
        return i == other.i; // Decorators are equal if their i is equal
    }
```

Now you can do

```
        map.put(new Decorator(3, "some string"), "some value");
        System.out.println(map.get(new Decorator(3, "")));
```

because only the `int` field is used to search the map.

Comment: Can you clarify the solution? The code does not compile (`Decoder` should be `Decorator` - just a typo I think). But also, the sample code from the question `map.get(3)` used to demonstrate this class still returns `null`. Is the overridden `equals()` method actually used?

Comment: OK - I guess it's the `hashCode()` method that is relevant and used here, not `equals()` - but the implementation of `get()` in `HashMap` makes use of the provided key placed in the map (in this case `Decorator`) so `get()` fails to find the requested key (an integer). See [`first.key`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0f51e6326373ff7d4a4d9a0e3a2788401f73405d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L578) - which does not match the lookup `key`. (If I have misread the source, I would be grateful for any corrections.)

Comment: @andrewJames Yes, thanks. The `Decoder` was indeed just a typo, and I didn't see that the OP was calling `get` directly with an `int`. This clearly violates `Map`'s contract. I explained that now.